# Ubuntu 10 Citrix plugin

Tags: ubuntu, installation, citrix

I know very little about Citrix so I apologize if my question does not compute.

My employer uses Citrix to connect all employees to a Windows server. As I work on Linux, I need to find a way to connect to the same server.

I am told there is such a thing as a Citrix plugin for Ubuntu (which I can't find or I'm completely missing) and if it exists, I need helpful instructions on installing it.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your employer uses XenApp.  This allows a number of users to connect remotely to a windows server that hosts a number of user sessions.  In a gross simplification of what is going on, applications running in these sessions are screen captured and transmitted to the employee's desktop.  In fact, getting desktop applications to work in this environment takes some trickery. There are a number of cost and management advantages to the approach that I'm not going to get into.

Users connect to XenApp through Receiver.  At its most basic, Receiver is a client that speaks ICA, an enterprise grade RDP.  However, overtime implementations have been created that provide additional features.  E.g. support for streaming HD video, and support for variable network connectivity typical of 3G broadband.

Implementations of Receiver are available for download at the [Client Center](http://www.citrix.com/lang/English/lp/lp_2309126.asp).  There is a Linux version; however, it is basic ICA.  E.g. no features for dealing with variability of 3G network connectivity.  However, it should be enough to address your use case.

As @ortang pointed out, instructions for installing the ICA Client on Ubuntu are at [CitrixICAClientHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo).  This page links to additional steps required to install the XenApp web plugin, which you might need if a web browser is the starting point for accessing apps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `Citrix ICA Client` [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo) are some instructions to install.

Cheers